# Optimal Way to Setup Table Structure

Tags: mysql, database

I am designing a new MySQL backend system and I am faced with an issue and I am unsure of the optimal way to setup my table. Let's say I have a table called *cities*. Each city has a relation to a table *weather* which contains weather information for every month. To be simple let's say that the structure of the *cities* table is:

```
---------------
| ID |  Name  |
---------------
|  1 | City1  |
|  2 | City2  |
|  3 | City2  |
---------------
```

For weather, I have approximately 50 fields. For each month of the year I have the high temp, low temp, avg temp, avg precipitation. Having a table with 50 columns seems inefficient and it seems difficult to add new fields. The other option I can consider is to have a table with the following setup:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| ID | CityID |    Type   | Value  | Unit |  Month |
----------------------------------------------------
|  1 |    1   | high_temp |   50   |  F   |    1   |
|  2 |    1   | low_temp  |   35   |  F   |    1   |
|  3 |    1   | avg_temp  |   45   |  F   |    1   |
|  4 |    1   | avg_prec  |   10   |  IN  |    1   |
|  5 |    2   | high_temp |   60   |  F   |    1   |
|  6 |    2   | low_temp  |   50   |  F   |    1   |
|  7 |    2   | avg_temp  |   55   |  F   |    1   |
|  8 |    2   | avg_prec  |   2    |  IN  |    1   |
----------------------------------------------------
```

However, I have around 1000 cities in the database and will be extending this to the tens of thousands. Having a table with around 5 million rows seems to be excessive and I worry about query time.

What would be the optimal way to set this up, with a one-to-one relationship or the one-to-many relationship? Also, which would be more efficient for creating complex queries in which I try to search for cities based on multiple weather characteristics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have shown not normalized structure. Imagine questions like:

> what are the cities with high temp greater then 30 and low temp less
> then 15 in january?
>
> for city 1 when was max temp and min temp exceeded?

Query will be complicated for those ones.
And all questions involving several types of temp will give you a headache in the future.

The optimal way is to move temp values into columns:

```
ID | CityID |  HighTemp | LowTemp | AvgTemp | AvgPrec | Unit |  Month |
```

Now abovemensioned query is just simple select statement with appropriate where clause. You just need to ask yourself similar questions and think about how whould you answer it in concrete schema.

And believe, 1 millions of rows is just nothing for database engine with appropriate indexing.

Comment: As a follow up, I have a similar issue with a pricing table. There are around 50 different fields for the pricing compared to the 8 above, but no month data. In this case would it still be optimal to have a table with ~50 fields?

Comment: In most cases it will be optimal. But normalizing is not a universal panacea. I had a training at microsoft and the trainer advised just to do denormalization in some cases. But it is a big topic to talk about in comment. Remember to ask questions about data and answers will come.

Answer (score 0):

If your fields are not fixed then the structure you have currently is sound.

5 million is not that big number if we are talking of databases which are  built upright to handle large data.

You can significantly decrease query turnaround time, by putting index on the fields that you want to use as in your query as filters.